# Create directory using Nant

Tags: nant

Not sure if I'm just totally missing it but I couldn't not figure out how to create a new directory using Nant.  Is there built in functionality to do this? Can I just use the command prompt?  I tried something along the lines of:

```
<exec program="cmd" commandline="md c:\test" />
```

but it just opened up a command prompt on the screen and never finished...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [mkdir](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/mkdir.html) task:

```
<mkdir dir="one/two/three" />
```